# HTML Checkbox: automatic checkable prop update based on value with Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, django-templates

This is my JS file to make the checkboxes, i just want that the checked prop of the checkbox updates itself base on the value of the input because my template engine renders the value of the boolean fields directly to my input value attr.

But is not working

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function (e) {
        console.log($(this).val())
        value = $(this).val()
        $(this).prop('checked', value);
    });
});

<tr class="checkbox_widget_button">
                    <td>
                        <div class="card-header"> {{item.validation}}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="POST" name="validationFormName_{{item.id}}" id="validationFormId_{{item.id}}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{item.id}}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{user.profile.custom_user_id}}">
                                <label for="validation">{{item.validate|lower}}</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="validation" value="{{item.validate|lower}}"
                                    id="validation">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Hi, you did mentioned "the checkbox updates itself based on the value of the input", may I know what are the possible values of the input?

Comment: True or False  are the inputs, i set the True or False value to the attr value="" of the checkbox on page load, and i update it on click based on the attr checked="". but i can not manage to update the attr cheked="" on page load.

Comment: Can you just use an if statement?   {% item.validate|lower ==?? %}   <input type="checkbox" name="validation" value="{{item.validate|lower}}" checked>{%else%} <input type="checkbox" name="validation" value="{{item.validate|lower}}" >

Comment: Agree with @Adam James. Is there any reason why you can't set the checkbox directly to "checked" if the value was "true" during the first render?

Comment: i solved it, you guys where right i did try that, main problem was with {{item.validate|lower}} returning "true/false" as string, just needed to parse it onto js bool type and evething was straight fordward.Thank you i'm closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, main problem was {{item.validate|lower}} returned a "true" "false" string not boolean.

Just need to parse it and go to the most straight fordward solution.

```
{% for item in list_validations%}
<tr class="">
<td>
<div class="card-header"> {{item.validation}}</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="card-body">
<input type="checkbox" name="validation" value="{{item.validate|lower}}"
                                                id="validation_{{item.validation_id}}">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}


$.fn.toggleCheckbox = function () {
    this.prop('checked', !this.prop('checked'));
    if (this.prop('checked')) {
        this.attr('value', true)
    } else {
        this.attr('value', false)
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checkbox_widget_button").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.tagName != 'INPUT') {
            $(this).find("input:checkbox").toggleCheckbox();
            return false;
        }
    });
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        value = $(this).val() == "true"; //PARSE THE STRING TO BOOLEAN HERE SOLVES THE QUESTION
        checked = $(this).prop('checked');
        if (value != checked) {
            $(this).toggleCheckbox();
        }
    });
});
```